# Calling external APIs securely from SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I checked out the webcast 'Calling external APIs securely from SharePoint Framework'. Can that be used to call on-prem web-api without using azure?

If I wanted to host a web-api on premise and call if from Sharepoint online, what authentication, would i need to use on my web api?

Comment: You beat me to the question :) I think this is a real great use case and opens a whole lot of opportunity with Sharepoint as a presentation layer. Looking for great answers!

Answer (score 8):

This would only work with on-premises if you are using exactly the same identities cross environments. This most likely would require ADFS setup or on-premise being connected to Azure AD.

Key point is to ensure that when the identity is passed through the cookie from SharePoint Online, on-premises can use that to map it to on-premises identity.

We have not specifically tested this scenario, so can't provide deep technical details for this.